# How can I solve the 'NameError: name 'salary' is not defined' error in my Python test case using setUp method?

Tags: python

How to use setUp method in test cases

I am working through Python Crash Course, by Eric Mathes. I am stuck at test cases. The first task is to create an employee class, which I have. That works well when i create an instance. The next step is to create a test case for the class which I did as below

But when I run the test case I get:

`NameError: name 'salary' is not defined.`

I understand I can't call a variable outside a function if I have only defined the variable inside the function. I just thought the `self.salary = salary` after defining `setUp` would take care of that.
I need your help.

```
class Employee():
    """creates a ledger of employees"""

    def __init__(self, first, last, salary):
        """initalizes the atributes of the employee class"""
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.salary = salary 
        msg = self.first.title() + " " + self.last.title() +\
         "." + " Salary: " + str(self.salary)
        print(msg)
        
    def give_raise(self, raises=5000):
        """increases employee salary by a defined amount"""
        
        self.salary += raises
        
        print(self.salary)
```

```
import unittest
from employee import Employee

class EmployeeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test that class works"""
    
    def setUp(self):
        """Initialize an instance and attributes of the class"""
        self.employee_1 = Employee('kim', 'menace', 50000)
        self.salary = salary
        
        
    def test_give_default_raise(self):
        """tests that default raise is 5000"""
        self.employee_1.give_raise()
        
        self.assertEqual(raises, 5000)
        
unittest.main()
```

Comment: Indeed, it is not defined in the `EmplyeeTest`. Now, what is the purpose of `self.salary = salary` line in the `setUp()` method? You don't need it, just remove it

Comment: Note you will face problem with `self.assertEqual(raises, 5000)` because `raises` is not defined. Probably you want to assert that `self.employee_1.salary` is 55000. `self.assertEqual(self.employee_1.salary, 55000)`

Comment: def setUp(self, salary)

Comment: If it helps, you can see solutions for exercises in Python Crash Course 2e [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/solutions/). Solutions for the third edition are [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_3e/solutions/).

Comment: Thank you so much @japhyr.  I have all the resources I need now.

Answer (score 0):

It's because salary is defined inside the object, but not in the Test class.